# My multithread creates or overwrites an extra/existing thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I want to spread a test over multiple threads, so first I divide the total numbers I want tested equally over the amount of threads I want (including remainder). Then I assign the testing that range of numbers to each thread. Everytime the test is positive, a counter is incremented. I test it over a range from 0 to 123, as I know what the result should be, but whenever I assign more then 1 thread to the task, I get the wrong result. When debugging, I noticed that after the starting of the threads, the current line skips back to assigning a new thread. I don't understand why. I have the counter protected by a lock, which as far as i know is working properly. Here is the corresponding code:

```
for (int n = 0; n < remainder; n++)
{
      workers[n] = new Thread(() => CountNumbers(startvalue + n * (tasks + 1), startvalue + (n + 1) * (tasks + 1), modulus));
}
for (int m = remainder; m < nrthreads; m++)
{
      workers[m] = new Thread(() => CountNumbers(startvalue + remainder * (tasks + 1) + (m - remainder) * tasks, startvalue + remainder * (tasks + 1) + (m - remainder + 1) * tasks, modulus));
}
for (int k = 0; k < nrthreads; k++)
{
      workers[k].Start();
}
for (int k = 0; k < nrthreads; k++)
{
      workers[k].Join();
}
```

the "problem" arises when `workers[k].Start()` is finished for all k, then it for some reason overwrites the last thread in `workers`.

I'm relative new to C#, so I struggle with finding the flaw. It is for school, so hints in the right direction are probably more appropiate then clean answers.

Comment: Have you considered using a Parallels.For or ForEach loop instead of doing all the "hard" work by yourself?

Comment: I have not, mainly because I'm confident in my mathematical part and less so in the more advanced loops available. I guess it would clean the code a bit.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common error in C# parallel programming. When you declare anonymous functions through lambda expressions, they capture any *variables* (not values) that they reference. In your case, all your threads are capturing the same variable instance for the `n` or `m` counter, leading all their executions to see its last value.

A simple way to resolve this is to declare another variable within the scope of your loop, and copy the counter to it. Since the scope is restricted to the loop, the variable will not be shared across your threads.

```
for (int nOuter = 0; nOuter < remainder; nOuter++)
{
    int n = nOuter;
    workers[n] = new Thread(() => CountNumbers(startvalue + n * (tasks + 1), startvalue + (n + 1) * (tasks + 1), modulus));
}
for (int mOuter = remainder; mOuter < nrthreads; mOuter++)
{
    int m = mOuter;
    workers[m] = new Thread(() => CountNumbers(startvalue + remainder * (tasks + 1) + (m - remainder) * tasks, startvalue + remainder * (tasks + 1) + (m - remainder + 1) * tasks, modulus));
}
```

**Edit**: You can simplify your code if you switch to using PLINQ or TPL constructs. The following should be equivalent to your entire logic:

```
Parallel.For(0, nrthreads, k =>
{
    if (k < remainder)
        CountNumbers(startvalue + k * (tasks + 1), startvalue + (k + 1) * (tasks + 1), modulus);
    else
        CountNumbers(startvalue + remainder * (tasks + 1) + (k - remainder) * tasks, startvalue + remainder * (tasks + 1) + (k - remainder + 1) * tasks, modulus);
});
```

Comment: Yes, this worked. I happen to have problems like these a lot, because I'm used to Haskell, where that problem practically never arises. Gotta get used to the sharing of variables.

Comment: It's an unfortunate trap. Eric Lippert blogged about it in [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx). Microsoft fixed the behaviour for `foreach` loops in C#5, but not for `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a lock on something because you are out of sync. I had the same kind of issue once before only  I was iterating a list and I had a valid index value (impossible to be out of range when you use list.Count) yet it was. Because I did not have a proper lock.
The issue is probably in your CountNumbers Method.